# Remove dictionary from list with multiple conditions

Tags: python, dictionary

```
list1 = [
   {'id': 1, 'country': 'Italy'},
   {'id': 2, 'country': 'Spain'},
   {'id': 3, 'country': 'Japan'}
]
```

I use this code to remove from `list1` every dictionary that has `country != Italy`:

```
list2 = [element for element in list1 if element['country'] == 'Italy']
```

But I to include in `list2` dictionaries which `country == 'Italy'` AND `country == 'Spain'` and remove all the others (or even better pop them from `list1` without creating another one). How can I do this in one line=

Comment: `[element for element in list1 if element['country'] in ['Italy','Spain']]` that would work IIUC. And list comprehension is about the only way to do that in one line. popping from list needs a loop, and not on the current list...

Comment: Popping will usually require more time since moving all elements is done in *O(n)* (unfortunately there seems to be no efficient method to provide a list of indices that should all be removed).

Comment: Nitpick: you mean `country == 'Italy'` OR `country == 'Spain'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a one-liner, you can use a *list comprehension* with an *in-place* list update:

```
list1[:] = [d for d in list1 if d['country'] in ('Spain', 'Italy')]
```